# JSF EL expressions to check empty string in propery file?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, el

I have to check if my property file is empty for certain label based on that I have to render the element but even when the label is empty i still get the element displaying key:

```
           <h:panelGroup  rendered="#{not empty I18N['key_hint_message'] }">
          <h:outputLabel id="hint_label" value="#{I18N['key_label_hint']}
           "></h:outputLabel>
          <h:outputText value="#{I18N['key_hint_message']}" ></h:outputText>
          </h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: I am sorry then what should I use to check if #{I18N['key_hint_message']} is empty or not

Comment: I thought sub expressions need to be under braces and I am so wrong

Comment: I changed the expression but still my panel group is getting displayed      Hint:???key_hint_message???

Comment: Question looks indeed better now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ResourceBundle#containsKey()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ResourceBundle.html#containsKey(java.lang.String)) for this.

```
<h:panelGroup rendered="#{I18N.containsKey('key_hint_message')}">
    <h:outputLabel value="#{I18N['key_label_hint']}" />
    <h:outputText value="#{I18N['key_hint_message']}" />
</h:panelGroup>
```

You'd better not rely on default format of missing keys as this can be overriden by a custom resource bundle resolver.

Answer (score 0):

JSF implementation displays by defaults missing resources as `???resource???`, So you can use the `fn:contains` JSTL function in your `rendered` attribute like this:

```
 <h:panelGroup  rendered="${not fn:contains(I18N['key_hint_message'], '???')}">
      <h:outputLabel id="hint_label" value="#{I18N['key_label_hint']}"/>
      <h:outputText value="#{I18N['key_hint_message']}" />
 </h:panelGroup>
```